# How to only forward port by ssh, not enter the remote's prompt?

Tags: ssh

For example, I execute `ssh -L 1:localhost:1`, I hope it show is it successfully only, if success, just blocking, do not show the welcome infomation and enter the remote's prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the -N option; it will establish connection, then block until killed or interrupted.

As an aside, you cannot bind the port `1` (or any port under 1024) unless you're root; and even so it is a very bad idea. I hope `1` here was just a stand-in for a real port you're using. :)

Comment: I know, I just give an virtual example.